# Collect by function with parameter in Java Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

From the tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html), I see I can group objects by attribute:

```
Map<Person.Sex, List<Person>> byGender =
    roster
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender));
```

What if I need to group by a method that takes a parameter, for example `steve.get("height")` instead of `steve.getHeight()`?  I suspect this can be done with a lambda, but I can't find the correct syntax.  What I've got right now:

```
people.stream().collect(Collectcors.groupingBy(p -> p.get("height")));
```

What is the correct syntax to use to group by the result of a lambda function?

Comment: Well what is the compile error? How does look like the map you're trying to assign the result to? What does this `get` method do?

Comment: Does `Person` have a method called `get`? What's the compile error? If your code doesn't compile and you don't understand why, it's helpful to post the compilation error.

Comment: In agreement with @AlexisC 's  comment, please edit your question to include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Alright.  The specific error is irrelevant.  I thought it was implied by saying `steve.get("height")` that `Person.get(String)` is indeed a function.  Anyway, I figured out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
people.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.get("height"), Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: It's great if you solved your problem but I suggest that you include the compile error and the type of the map you tried to assign the result too. As it stands, your question/answer is not very helpful to the community... because `p -> p.get("height")` could be a valid function to group by.

Comment: You didn’t say in your question that you changed the resulting type from `… List<Person>>` to `… Set<Person>>`. If you did, an appropriate answer appeared immediately. However, if you just thought about the fact that you changed your expectation from `List` to `Set` you understood that it has nothing to do with the *syntax* of the grouping function.